# magento2 cannot override custom controller

Tags: magento2

i have overridden my custom controller in **etc/di.xml**

```
<preference for="Magento\Catalog\Block\Product\ListProduct" type="Vendor\Module\Block\Catalog\Product\ListProduct" />
<preference for="ToolbarModel" type="Vendor\Module\Block\Catalog\Product\ProductList\Toolbar" />    <!--ToolbarModel: alias for Magento\Catalog\Model\Product\ProductList\Toolbar -->
                    <!--Override for Block catalog Search layer -->
<preference for="Magento\LayeredNavigation\Block\Navigation" type="Vendor\Module\Block\CatalogSearch\Layer" />
                    <!-- Override model: Catalog Resource-->
<preference for="Magento\Catalog\Model\ResourceModel\Product\Collection" type="Vendor\Module\Model\Catalog\Resource\Product\Collection" />
```

**my etc/frontend/di.xml** is as

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
 <config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:ObjectManager/etc/config.xsd">
                    <!--Override controller -catalogsearch-->
<preference for="Magento\CatalogSearch\Controller\Result\Index" type="Vendor\Module\Controller\CatalogSearch\ResultController" />
```

Comment: move your di.xml to etc/frontend

Comment: Please see updated answer after moving di to etc/frontend...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change your controller code to :

```
namespace Vendor\Module\Controller\CatalogSearch;

use Magento\Catalog\Model\Layer\Resolver;
use Magento\Catalog\Model\Session;
use Magento\Framework\App\Action\Context;
use Magento\Framework\App\ResourceConnection;
use Magento\Store\Model\StoreManagerInterface;
use Magento\Search\Model\QueryFactory;

class ResultController extends \Magento\CatalogSearch\Controller\Result\Index
{

    public function __construct(
        Context $context,
        Session $catalogSession,
        StoreManagerInterface $storeManager,
        QueryFactory $queryFactory,
        Resolver $layerResolver
    ) {
        parent::__construct(
            $context,
            $catalogSession,
            $storeManager,
            $queryFactory,
            $layerResolver
        );
    }
    public function execute()
    {
        echo 'my controller';exit;
    }

}
```

**N.B: You should go with plugin**

**[Updated]**

I am going to build a **around** plugin example for you.

Put following config to **Vendor\Module/etc/frontend/di.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:ObjectManager/etc/config.xsd">
    <type name="Magento\CatalogSearch\Controller\Result\Index">
        <plugin name="stackexchange_catalog_search_result" type="Vendor\Module\Controller\CatalogSearch\ResultController" sortOrder="1"/>
    </type>
</config>
```

Create a plugin class **Vendor\Module/Controller/CatalogSearch/ResultController.php**

```
namespace Vendor\Module\Controller\CatalogSearch;

class ResultController
{


}
```

For more information [Click Here](http://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.1/extension-dev-guide/plugins.html)

Comment: could yu please help with the plugin code for etc di

Comment: Check now only updated answer.

Comment: Could you explain when and whats the use of around before and afterexecute

Comment: If you need some thing before execute then use beforeExecute(), If you need something at the same line of execute call then use aroundExecute(), If you need after execute then use afterExecute(). Clear?

Comment: i had used as yu mentioned, but even my aroundExecute() is getting called (ie 'my controller' is also printing) and after commenting echo , Magentos core execute() is also getiing called

Comment: i have updated my controller... at $query->setId(0)
                ->setIsActive(1)
                ->setIsProcessed(1);  this point, the controllers goes to core again

Comment: Check updated comment inside 'aroundExecute'

Comment: i commented return $proceed... from my custom controller, could you please check what is wrong, im trying to get products searched from custom search engine from custom search engine, i get blank screen

Comment: i have full updated code here, im struck from past 2 days.. need help  http://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/122625/magento2-catalogsearch-result-not-displaying